How to prevent the re-creation of default mkinitcpio preset file upon kernel update?
Since I’m using custom mkinitcpio presets to generate UKIs, I deleted the default preset file inside /etc/mkinitcpio.d/ that came during system installation.
Unfortunately, when pacman updates the kernel, the default preset file comes back, and the associated initramfs images get recreated automatically on top of my UKIs. The minor consequence is the waste of space on my boot partition, the major one is the inability to boot my system again if I forget to delete the undesired images before shutdown.
I haven’t found how is triggered the creation of the preset file. The linux kernel package file does not include it. However there is a skeleton preset at /usr/share/mkinitcpio/hook.preset but I have no idea if it is really used during kernel update and how to prevent the generation of a new one.

Use an empty file?

NoExtract in /etc/pacman.conf, I suppose. I have no idea why you aren't overwriting it with what you need though.

@frostschutz That does the trick. As simple as that lol. Please write your suggestion as an answer so I can give your points.

@Tom Yan NoExtract prevents specified files to be copied from the package. But if a file is not part of the package, that would not work. Furthermore, after reading more carefully the arch wiki and performed some system exploration, I discovered that the default preset files are created with the rather complex /usr/share/libalpm/scripts/mkinitcpio script. I guess that can be re-configured with new pacman hooks and replacement scripts but I prefer to resolve the issue with the simple command touch /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset…

@TomYan Also, having multiple dedicated preset files is just a matter of tiding up things. Image generation is long enough to want to avoid to generate all of them every time a small modification is to be tested.

@BogeyJammer Ah, I didn't follow the recent changes. In the past preset files are static files shipped in kernel packages.

As @frostschutz said in the question’s comments:
"Use an empty file"
mkinitcpio will warn that it’s empty but since it’s here, any kernel update will not replace it with the default one.
